Find length of 3rd leg of a triangle (that is not a right triangle)
Assume I have any triangle $\triangle ABC$. I know that given the lengths two sides of the triangle and angle between them, I can find the length of the third side. In other words, given values of $AB$, $AC$, and  $\angle BAC$, I can find $BC$. What if instead of the angle, I know the length of $AD$ where $D$ is somewhere along $BC$ (i.e. points $B$, $C$, and $D$ are collinear). Can I still find the length of $BC$?
If I place the triangle on a cartesian plane with A at the origin and with the slope of BC $ = 1$, then I can write 3 equations for the circles with radii AB, AC, and AD, and 3 more for the slopes of BC, BD, and DC each being $1$. Will solving the 6 equations with 6 unknowns work? It wouldn't be fun.
I question it working because other orientations of the triangle on the plane lead to different results. If I place the triangle in the plane with B at the origin and C and D along the x axis, I only have 4 unknowns. However, I only have 3 equations from the circles since the slopes are $0$. I need another equation. Alternatively, if I place A at the origin and B (or C or D) along the x axis, I still only have 4 unknowns, but I get equations from 2 circles and 3 slopes and have too many equations.
What am I missing? Is there an easier way?

Your question makes no sense to me. I don't know what you assume after you say "$D$ is somewhere along $BC$. Please [edit] to clarify. A picture would help a lot.

Nothing about the location of D is assumed except that it lies on the line defined by BC and its distance from A is given.

Stewart's Theorem may-or-may-not be helpful to you. It relates the sides of a triangle, a "cevian" from one vertex to the opposite side, and the lengths into which that opposite side has been divided. If you can specify how exactly $AD$ meets $BC$ (as a median? an altitude? an angle bisector? a trisector? etc, etc, etc), then you "should be" able (barring weird degeneracies I haven't anticipated) to use the theorem to glean the length of $BC$ from the given info. However, lengths $AB$, $AC$, $AD$ alone are not enough to determine the $BC$.

"I know the length of AD where D is somewhere along BC (i.e. points B, C, and D are collinear). Can I still find the length of BC?"  Of course not.  There are an infinite number of points on the line BC and you have no idea which one you were give.

The answer is no. In the figure below, let $AB=4$, $AC=9$, and $AD=6$. That means that $B, C, D$ are on some circles with the given radii. Let's fix point $B$, then draw two lines from $B$, at non-zero angles with respect to $AB$ direction, at different slopes. The intersection with the other circles will give you $C, D$ in one case and $C', D'$ in the other. You can see that it's easy to construct cases where the $BC$ length is different than $BC'$.

